# Check if Iterable is a Map

Tags: javascript, dictionary, types, iterator

I have an object which I know to be iterable. I want to do something different depending on whether it's a `Map` or not. Here is an incomplete solution:

```
function toList(iterable) {
    let results = [];
    if (/* iterable is a map */) {
        for (let elem of iterable) {
            elem[1].key = elem[0];
            results.push(elem[1]);
        }
    } else {
        for (let elem of iterable) {
            results.push(elem);
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

Is there anything I could use to authoritatively check whether `iterable` is a Map or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keyword you are looking for here is [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof). It checks whether another Object is in the prototype chain of an object.

So in your case:

```
if (iterable instanceof Map) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/@@toStringTag) method:

```js
var iterable = new Map();

if (iterable.toString() == '[object Map]') {
  console.log('Map!');
}
```